# How to destructure dictionary while adding a function to the variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, destructuring

Consider that I have a function:

```
function doubleNo (no) {
   return no * 2
}
```

Now, this is what I want:

```
let oldDict = { var1: 2, var2: 3 }
// console.log(var1) -> 4
// console.log(var2) -> 6 Basically, I want to create a new dictionary such that the function `doubleNo` is applied to each key in the dictionary
```

Now, I understand we can destructure the dictionary as following:

```
const { var1, var2 } = oldDict // This will set values of var1 and var2 as 2, and 3
```

I went through the docs and couldn't find a direct method. Is it possible, or the only way is to create a let and then modify it?

```
let { var1, var2 } = oldDict
var1 = doubleNo(var1)
var2 = doubleNo(var2)
```

I was thinking if we can have a single line method to destructure the dictionary with the method applied

Answer (score 3):

You can map over [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and convert it back to an object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
function doubleNo (no) {
   return no * 2
}
let old = { var1: 2, var2: 3 };
let res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(old).map(([k,v])=>[k, doubleNo(v)]));
// you could also destructure var1 and var2 here
console.log(res);
```